# Debugging unhandled HTTP request to WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-web-api

I am calling my WebApi server methods from a console client and most of the calls work.
Some don't.
My routing seems fine but obviously there is a bug.
Is there a way to set a breakpoint somewhere ( earlier than my controller method ) which will allow me to trace the source of the error.

Comment: Do the calls that fail in the console app work if you call them another way (directly)?

Comment: Nope. I get http 500 error.

Comment: Multiple actions were found that match the request

Comment: i think you will need to post the URL you are calling and the server side controller class. (and your route config). it could be as simple as having two methods in the one controller and the routing engine doesnt know which one to match to because they are both 'identical' according to it.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You can create your custom `DelegatingHandler` and in there you can play with routes. Here is example: `public class UserAuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
       
        private const string logon_route_name = "Logon";
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            // must have existing route name or call fails
            bool logonRoute = (GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes[logon_route_name].GetRouteData("", request) != null);.........`

Answer (score 0):

You must have two methods in the controller that is being called that are 'identical' to the routing engine. eg

```
public class FooController
{
    public void Get1() { }
    public void Get2() { }
}
```

if you attempt to call `somedomain.com/api/foo` you will get a 500 server error

> Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nSystem.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

Remember that in WebApi (by default) there is no `{action}` part of the route:

> {controller}/{id}

meaning the API has a convention for which method is called.

[See this](http://www.cloudydeveloper.com/differences-between-asp-net-web-api-and-asp-net-mvc-routing/) article explaining more